# Eclipse PDT - What does "Build Project" command do?

Tags: eclipse-pdt

If I'm not mistaken PHP code is interpreted by the server, so what does "Build Project" command in Eclipse PDT do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is doing on server, is doing on server. This is an IDE. Build project with PHP Language nature doing similar thing as with Java, JavaScript and other languages in Eclipse IDE:

- Indexing
- Parsing
- Validating
- Caching

Special plugins may also autorun external command.

Comment: AST tree. Required while validating, type inferencing and code assist.